# Teeth with removed nerves. Possible remineralization?

Tags: dentistry, tooth-decay

I have friends and acquaintances having remineralized and healed their teeth, some of whom having quite some cavities. I really doubted it but decided to do some research instead and it is possible indeed.

The difference with me is that I have around 5 teeth, if not more which had their nerves removed. Is there any hope? Common sense says 100% impossible but please share if any solutions for that are known.